# Nginx upload_module will only store files in /var/www

Tags: nginx

Current setup:

- nginx listening on port 80, forwarding example.com requests to Apache on 8080
- Apache listening on port 8080, hooked up to Django app via wsgi
- Django form uploads image to subdomain photos.example.com/upload/

This seems to be from my configuration file in nginx, but I can't put my finger on it. I mostly tried changing the upload_store directive in nginx. 
I want the user's uploaded photos to be stored in /var/www/dev/source/nginx/media/

The best I can do right now is symlink from /var/www to the folder I want them in.

Relevant nginx configuration:

```
server {
        client_max_body_size 100m;
        listen 80;
        server_name photos.example.com;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/photos.example.com/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/photos.example.com/error.log;


        # Upload form should be submitted to this location
        location /upload {
                # Pass altered request body to this location

                # Store files to this location
                upload_store /var/www/dev/source/nginx/media 1;
                # Set specified fields in request body
                upload_set_form_field $upload_field_name.name "$upload_file_name";
                upload_set_form_field $upload_field_name.content_type "$upload_content_type";
                upload_set_form_field $upload_field_name.path "$upload_tmp_path";
        }
        # Pass altered request body to a proxy

        location / {
                root /var/www/dev/source/nginx/media;
        }
}
```

Relevant `models.py`:

```
def rename_image(instance,filename):
    random = ''.join([choice(letters) for i in xrange(10)])
    today = datetime.date.today()
    userid = instance.user.username
    filename = '_'.join([today.strftime('%s'),userid,random,filename])
    return'/'.join(['images','users',userid,filename])


class Users(models.Model):
    user        = models.OneToOneField(User)
    ...
    photo       = models.ImageField(upload_to=rename_image)
```

### EDIT:

When I try to set it to another path (made up a directory called imgz as a test), this is in the nginx error log: (I did then also create imgz to see if that would fix it, but it did not)

2012/12/02 09:37:44 [error] 31229#0: *56472 open()     "/var/www/dev/source/nginx/media/imgz/users/1354424400_lmDdkskvEPbrtUYBudgzsLjiOXvywx_gwslfBWlBk_me.jpg" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: xx.xx.example.example, server: photos.example.com, request: "GET /imgz/users/1354424400_lmDdkskvEPbrtUYBudgzsLjiOXvywx_gwslfBWlBk_me.jpg HTTP/1.1", host: "photos.example.com", referrer: "http://dev.example.com/lmDdkskvEPbrtUYBudgzsLjiOXvywx"

### EDIT2:

Actually, that's a GET request that happens after the POST. It's the Django app trying to display the image that was just uploaded. The POST of the form is almost always successful if I remember correctly. If I change the path, it simply makes a different path in /var/www.

Comment: Any errors/warning in the log when setting other paths?

Comment: Ah! I forgot all about that, thanks. I'll add it to my post as well.
When I set it to /var/www/dev/source/nginx/media/images, I get the open() error with the message of "No such file or directory". Obviously I then created the directory 'images', and it still gives the same error.

Comment: So is the image uploaded correctly, and does it actually exist in `var/www/dev/source/nginx/media/...`?